# How to URL route based on UICulture settings?

Tags: asp.net, routes, globalization

I have ASP.NET 4 project (not MVC). I need to create url route based on user input language.

Project has only two languages "he" and "en".

User can enter the site and if his culture is set to anything besides he-IL i want to re-route him to website.com/en/ otherwise to website.com/he/

Default.aspx should remain same page which uses Globalization features translate values based on user's culture settings in browser.

How can i do that? what should i do besides writing a route in Global.asax and How to write this route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to do something unintended with Routing.

If the language in URL does nothing and you need for it to appear in URL only then you either make hackish solution with HTTP modules rewriting urls to remove it and add back to generated html or simply map the same site to two virtual folders /en and /he in IIS and make a simple Default.aspx page at / to redirect to appropriate one based on user culture.

Comment: thanks for the input. This is exact solution i was trying to avoid but probably i have no other choice...

Answer (score 1):

This shouldnt be hard.  Yes the Global.ascx is the best place to start.

First map the Routes,

```
    protected void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        //Contact route for EN culture
        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "contactRouteEN",
            "en/contact",
            "~/Contact.aspx"
        );

        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "contactRouteHE",
            "he/contact",
            "~/Contact.aspx"
        );
    }

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

That much establishes the routes.

The problem your describing sounds more like a Globalization issue than url routing problem.  The url portion of the issue will be cosmetic to the user but won't attack the underlying issue in my view.  ASP.Net provides facilities for Globalization.  For example you can use LocalResources.  To do this for the pages at your applications root level (not nested inside folders)
Right click the website and choose Add ASP.Net Folder
Choose App_LocalResources.
Right click the App_LocalResources folder and choose Add Item
Choose Resource File.

It is important that you name the file according to the culture you plan to target

You can create the first file to be Contact.aspx.resx to be the default resource file (maybe english?)

ASP.Net will try to find the most specific culture to match the resource files to and will resort to the default if a more specific is not provided.

The naming convention follows PageName.aspx.languageID-cultureId.resx

You could have Contact.aspx.he.resx

In a label control for example you could set it like this

```
<asp:Label ID="lbContactMessage" runat="server" Text="something" meta:resourcekey="yourmatchingkeyfromresourcefile"></asp:Label>
```

For more info see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx

Comment: your question : How to write this route.  I answered this.  as far as globalization on whole site you can use Global resources and local resources but from your question I assumed you already knew this part.   I'm not hunting bounty I'm actually trying to answer your question?  Can you provide more details

Comment: contact.aspx which leads to contactRoute ie. contact/ should be the same physical file for all languages. So if i selected English as primary language i want to go to en/contact/ instead of contact/ while both pointing to the same physical file. How do i write this route?

Comment: I know that, what i need is to know what route to redirect when i change to another language? I have DropDownList that changes language, let's say i get RouteName and change GE to EN for example? I have links all over the website pointing to Routes, how do i integrate languages in them ? Do you know understand the problem?

Comment: so you have a link such as ~/en/SomePage.aspx.  If they were viewing in spanish you want clicking this link to turn the culture to english?

Comment: If you are redirecting in the dropdown selection changed event then you would some complex redirection logic to deal with.  Heres what I would suggest.  It would help to have strong typing of your routes.  You  could create a new static class for MyRoutes.  You  could nest inside a static class and call it ContactPage inside you could nest a set of routes for each language you wish to support.  You would have 3 static readonly strings RouteName, Url, ApplicationPath.  Then you could find the route data by using MyRoutes.ContactPage.English.Url  or something like that.

Comment: Heres another tip, since you would be applying url rerouting for every page based on selected culture you could define a base class for all of your pages to inherit from and perform the logic there to save work.

Comment: Do you think it will work? I mean Routes defined during application start event while your solution is runtime. Will i have access to Session at the time i re-route my application?